# Linking directly to an app on Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I have noticed that now when I click on an app link, instead of directly going to the Google Play App, the browser opens a window with selection choices of: Browser, Google Play...

The link is used from within a browser and not an app so the market:// is not relevant.

I use the standard format:

```
http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

Is this a recent change? I think that previously the link was opening in Google Play directly, without the intermediate window?

Is it possible today to open the app in Google Play directly without this selection window??

Comment: Is for an android app or a website?

Comment: @AWinter Of course the link is used from within a browser and not an app so the market:// is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use following code to open the play store directly

```
startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>")));
```

Keep in mind that this solution will only works if the play store app is installed on the target device. In the case it is not installed the `android.content.ActivityNotFoundException` will be fired. So handle this exception and open the http:// url instead of the market:// one.

```
try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<package_name>")));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id="<package_name>")));
}
```

Comment: Did you just copy AWinter's code block, made a couple of minor changes and post?? Or is it the other way round?

Comment: Unlikely, since this answer is older than AWinter's.

Comment: Of course the link is used from within a browser and not an app so the market:// is not relevant.

Comment: @Simon: I thought I saw an edit, updated and saw the near identical code. I know the time-stamp shows the opposite but an edit made quick enough after answering will not show the "edited" stamp. Any way, moving on. Beauty of Open Source I suppose. ;-)

Comment: First I answeres the question with the first line of code. After that I searched my code for the exception, edited my post and wrote a more detailed answer.

Comment: I just made atest with chrome and used the market:// link. Everything worked perfect.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.  Google added the intermediate window by design to allow the user the choice of either viewing the page in the browser, keeping the browser experience, or in the Play application.  The only thing you can really do is petition Google for a change but it's unlikely they'll honor such a request.

Comment: Did you just copy Christian's code block, made a couple of minor changes and post?? Or is it the other way round?

Comment: @Simon That's the code block from the link in my answer I added and no I didn't.

Comment: Of course the link is used from within a browser and not an app so the market:// is not relevant.

Comment: market://details?id= does work from the browser on a phone, test it, obviously it's useless to a non android device or with with no Play installed unless you specifically called it something like "open in Play"

Comment: @AWinter I have tested market://details?id= in a browser and it didn't work. What browser did you use? I use Chrome.

Comment: @AWinter Yes I have latest version of Chrome

Comment: If you click the same http link either from an SMS/Email app, it will open the play store by default. If you paste that url in Chrome (on an Android phone) though it will go to the web version of the page. To make matters even more interesting, if you click the link from within an email in the browser (browser version of Gmail), it will open up the play store. So the posted answer doesn't make sense in that case?

Answer (score 0):

If your talking about when using android OS, then this should fix it

Settings -> Manage Apps -> Your Browser -> Clear defaults